# Cannot resolve symbol FragmentCompat

Tags: android

I've just pasted this [file](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) in a new project, but I'm getting:

> Cannot resolve symbol FragmentCompat;

any help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to add support library v13.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:version_of_library'
```

Android also you need to add support library `support-v4`, because `support-v13` depends on `support-v4`

More information you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/package-summary.html)

Comment: The `support-v4` dependency will be handled automatically by Gradle; you do not need to add it manually.

Comment: AFAIK, `support-v13` already includes (through dependency) `support-v7` and `support-v4`, so there is no need to explicitely add the last 2.
Likewise, `support-v7` includes `support-v4`.

Answer (score 11):

In Android studio, right click on the project, select "Open Module Settings" and add support library v13 like so:

[image]