# Cannot resolve symbol 'FragmentCompat' - Camera2VideoJava - Target to API 29

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, androidx, android-camera2

I have a project that has been using **[Camera2VideoJava](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2VideoJava)**.  I am **upgrading to API 29** (AndroidX) but now the [Camera2VideoFragment.java file](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/Camera2VideoJava/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java) get the **following errors**:

1. > Cannot resolve symbol 'v13'

   for this line:
   `import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat;`
2. > Cannot resolve symbol 'FragmentCompat'

   for this line:
   `implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {`

The issue is that `android.support.v13` does not get imported into my project anymore since AndroidX handles it.  With updating to API 29 & AndroidX, typically the import is automatically suggested by Android Studio when it changes.

**Initially expected solution:**

The import (`import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat;`) would typically change to something like `import androidx.core.app.FragmentCompat;` or `androidx.legacy.app.FragmentCompat` (as suggested [here](https://androidx.de/androidx/legacy/app/FragmentCompat.html)), which would resolve both errors above.  However, neither import exists.

**Potential Solution?**

I believe the import is not suggested/does not exist because [FragmentCompact was deprecated](https://www.google.com/search?q=api%2029%20fragmentcompact%20deprecated&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS752US752&oq=api%2029%20fragmentcompact%20deprecated&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.10081j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and now [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) is recommended, so my only idea then would be to use Fragment instead of FragmentCompact, but that would create other issues with :

- `if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {`
- `FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, VIDEO_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS);`
- `FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(parent, VIDEO_PERMISSIONS,REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS);`

since `Fragment` does not have those methods. So then I would have to replace/rewrite the functionality for those, which.. may work? but I'm not questioning if I'm taking a long route for no good reason here.

Additional:

- My understanding is that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220233/cannot-resolve-symbol-fragmentcompat) does not apply in this case since it will create duplicate imports with AndroidX

---

**Is there a better solution to resolve the `FragmentCompat` issue for [Camera2VideoJava](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2VideoJava) when updating to API 29?**

Comment: After dedicating several hours to this issue, I was able to make this app work in Android 29 by changing FragmentCompat to ActivityCompat. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I also faced the same problem as you, and tried adding the support library as suggested in your linked solution. Can you explain further your changes? For example, ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() expects an activity instead of a fragment in its argument so I am not sure what to do next. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and fastest way that worked for me:
Changing all the references in the build.gradle to:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

in the Camera2VideoFragment add:

```
import androidx.legacy.app.FragmentCompat;
```

&

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

Changing the package name to mine in line 20 of the fragment_camera2_video.

```
<com.yyyy.xxxx.AutoFitTextureView
android:id="@+id/texture"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

That is it - works like magic

By the way - in case that you are looking for a camera app template, I found out the following much better.
It demonstrate camera2API, permissions & video capturing. but also allows you to make image capturing while recording.
link
[Camera2Video+image capture](https://github.com/mobapptuts/android_camera2_api_video_app)

(You will need to change ContextCompat to ActivityCompat)